# Send and receive JSON content in Event Hub

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub

I am using below code to send content to Event Hub which is being read by Logic App . In Logic App when I select content-type as **application/octet-stream**, it works fine but I get Content body as encoded, and when I select **application/json** as content-type then it fails. How can I modify my content below so that my logic app reads the json sent from below code.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numOfEvents; i++)
            {
                if (!eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Event"))))
                {
                    // if it is too large for the batch
                    throw new Exception($"Event {i} is too large for the batch and cannot be sent.");
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly decode the content that is getting triggered from the event hub using `decodeBase64()` in your logic app. One of the workarounds that you can do is simply add a compose connector and use `decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])` for decoding your content.

Here is a screenshot of the logic app for your reference:

[image]

**Output :-**

[image]